# Basis for set of $k$-periodic sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $k ≥ 1$, and let $S_{k}$ be the set of $k$-periodic sequences. Find a basis for $S_ {k}$. What is its dimension?

---

**My thoughts**

I know that a basis needs to be linearly independent and spanning. But I do not know how to represent $ S_{k} $ nor how to visualize it. A basic detailed explanation would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers is $k$-periodic if $a_{n+k}=a_n$.

Based on this, a $k$-periodic sequence is determined by its first (or any consecutive) $k$ elements: $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k$.

These can be arbitrary, so the dimension is $k$ and you can write up a basis by letting $(a_i=1$ and $a_j=0$ for $j\le k,\ j\ne i)_{i=1,2,\dots,k}$.